# Javascript: Better to call one event handler that does multiple things than to call multiple event handlers that each do one thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

EDIT: To be more specific, I'm speaking performance-wise when I ask for which is better, since I'm worried about scaling this situation up. If you have comments on whether or not one way or another is better practice, then that's welcome as well, but my main concern is performance.

I've been playing around with coding a video game using HTML and Javascript/jQuery, and I'm dealing with a situation in which on clicking an object can have multiple effects, from opening menus to playing animations to triggering other events to undoing previous actions and removing other event handlers.

The way I see it there are two main ways I can handle it. I could either create one big event handler that does everything and decides what to do based on various states that I monitor in the page. e.g.:

```
$btn_Foo.on('click', function() {

    if(condition_A) {
        Do_Action_A();
    } else {
        Do_Action_B();
    }

    if(condition_B) {
        Do_Action_C();
    }

});
```

The other is I have each of the processes doled out to different event handlers that can be turned off and on, and state checking may just take place within each individual function. e.g.:

```
$btn_Foo.on('click', Do_Action_A);
$btn_Foo.on('click', Do_Action_C);

//In some other function
if(!condition_A) {
    $btn_Foo.off('click', Do_Action_A);
    $btn_Foo.on('click', Do_Action_B);
}
```

I'm leaning more towards the second option mostly because I'm building my javascript with a modular and more flexible design, but the main thing I'm worried about is that having many different event handlers might cause some noticeable performance issues. I might have as many as a dozen of these event handlers on a single object (and there will at least a hundred of these objects), so I don't know if the overhead from calling several times more event handlers will have a significant impact. If not, then I'll just go with option 2.

EDIT 2: After reading more on the topic, I realized it's important to mention I'm using event delegation to attach the event handler, so the bit about the event being attached to thousands of elements is probably a non-issue. Still, my original concern of there being maybe a dozen of these event handlers still stands.

Comment: This will probably be closed as it's probably very opinionated and not within the suggested use of SO.  Before that happens..it's more efficient to have one function.  Function calls are generally expensive.

Comment: To be more specific and objective, I'm concerned about the performance impact and whether or not it's significant. I guess that might not be very clear from the title. I'll edit the body if that helps.

Comment: This is one of those, "run both 1,000,000 times with a timer running" questions. Found this curious myself, though, so even though I'm years late to the party, I may just try that out myself.